# Understanding conditional expectation on an element of sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to understand the definition
$$E[X|B] = E[X|\sigma(B)]$$

I am bit lost because $E[X|B] = \frac{E[X 1_B]}{P(B)}$ and $B \in \sigma(B)$. So this let me think $P(B) \leq P(\sigma(B))$

Which makes me question how  $$E[X|B] = E[X|\sigma(B)]$$

Comment: The 'new' expectation is ${E[X \cdot 1_B] \over PB} 1_B + {E[X \cdot 1_{B^c}] \over P{B^c}} 1_{B^c}$. (Just ato avoid any ambiguity between old & new.)

Comment: @copper.hat how about the $E[X]1_\Omega$ wouldn't this add an extra constant?

Comment: @TJT I don't understand what you are asking. Implicit in my answer is that $PB \in (0,1)$, if not then adjust the above expression by removing the term corresponding to zero probability.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional expectation is not a constant anymore. For a finitely generated $\sigma$ algebra, like here $\sigma(B) = \{ \emptyset, B, B^c, \Omega \}$, it is constant on the partition sets, i.e. on $B$ and $B^c$ and attains the old conditional expectation value there. So (assuming $0 < P[B] < 1$)
$$E[X|\sigma(B)] = E[X|B] 1_B + E[X | B^c] 1_{B^c}.$$
Now we can insert an $\omega \in B$ and get back the constant $E[X|B]:= \frac{E[X 1_B]}{P[B]}$.

Although it might seem annoying at first having to carry the indicator functions, this comes from the fact that we use conditional expectations $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ to contain information from $\mathcal{G}$. In our case, it contains the information whether or not we are in $B$, thus the indicator functions. After that is "decided", we get back the old conditional expectation $E[X|B]$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It's definitely clearer to me now. I want to clarify two more things:
1. Why the expression is not $E[X|\sigma(B)] = E[X|B] 1_B + E[X | B^c] 1_{B^c} + E[X | \Omega] 1_\Omega + E[X | \emptyset] 1_\emptyset$? 
2. My understanding of Indicator function is like $1_B(\omega) = 1 \ if \ \omega \in A$, if I want to write out the $\omega$    in    $E[X|B] 1_B$, what is the proper way to do it? 

sorry if my question is stupid